# How to get logs of iOS device which is supervised with Apple configurator?

Tags: ios, xcode, logstash, device

**Is there a way to get device logs or system logs of device which is supervised using Apple configurator**

Selecting Window > Devices from the Xcode does not work, I have checked my mac machine system logs, it also does not show any logs related to device.

Any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect it to the device which supervised it to get the logs using iPhone Configuration Utility.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4941620?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thanks a ton, it saved my day.

Comment: This link might help others as well https://kb.air-watch.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001664848-Gathering-iOS-Logs?mobile_site=true